# I am trying to generate pdf using pdfbox in jsp but it is not working why?

Tags: jsp, pdfbox

I am trying to generate pdf using pdfbox in jsp but it is not working.
It is working in java but it is not working in jsp. It is giving error:-

An error occurred at line: [11] in the jsp file: [/PdfGenerator.jsp]
PDDocument cannot be resolved to a type

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.sql.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%

 PDDocument document = new PDDocument();    

document.save("C:/Users/kuldeep100/Downloads/k.pdf");

document.close();
%>    
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF GENERATOR</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you insisting in using JSP. You could use a service for generating PDF. JSP is not a proper place to do this. I highly recommend to look into MVC.

Comment: Have you checked that the pdfbox library is in the .war file? What IDE are you using? What PDFBox version are you using? How do you build? Maven?

Comment: This is now several weeks ago. Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add pdfbox.jar (downloaded from [the official site](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi)) in your application's WEB-INF/lib directory.